# How can I enforce network time quotas? Or page request limits?

Tags: proxy, squid

I would like to enforce network time quotas, i.e. limit users to a given amount of network time per day (but without using fixed time ranges like with the iptables time module). Or alternatively limit the number of page requests.
How can I do this?

I found [this](ftp://ftp.tuwien.ac.at/.vhost/www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.4/manuals/ext_time_quota_acl.8.html), which looks like it might do what I want, but I can't find any "ext_time_quota_acl" in my squid3 installation.
Do I need to manually install ext_time_quota_acl somehow? Does it work with squid3?

Or are there easier/other ways to do this, like with iptables or ufw for example?

Note: This is for outgoing connections, not incoming connections on a server, but since it is networking related, I thought it fit serverfault quite well. Can also be seen as incoming connections on a proxy server anyway.

Comment: Correct way to do it, install a proxy/websense and block all 'not-ralated' work website usage.

Comment: I already know how to implement the way you mentioned, but a time/page-quota seems more flexible and much easier to manage. And it is what I am looking for now.

Comment: 'Seem'. What if someone need to work more online ? btw, http://www.websense.com/support/article/kbarticle/What-is-quota-time-and-how-does-it-work